# Switching from Antlr4-Java to ParseKit-Objective-C: Channels in ParseKit?

Tags: java, objective-c, grammar, antlr4, parsekit

**Problem:**
Don't know how to Translate the Contents of an Antlr4 ".g4" Grammar File to match the Grammar for [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com/index.html).

**Specifically:**
How to Translate `-> Channel(HIDDEN);` from Antlr4 Grammar to ParseKit Grammar.

**Context:**
I'm creating a .Framework in Objective-C/Xcode for iOS. I need to Generate a Parser that mimics the basic functionality of an Antlr4 Generated Parser in Java. The way to go about designing the functionality of the Parser isn't a problem; I am interested in learning more about the [Grammar Syntax for ParseKit](http://parsekit.com/grammars.html).

**Grammar Code:**

**[Antlr3](http://www.antlr3.org/)**:
`WHITESPACE : [ \t\r\n]+ {$channel=HIDDEN;}`

**[Antlr4](http://www.antlr.org/)**:
`WHITESPACE : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);`

**[ParseKit](http://parsekit.com/index.html)**:
`whitespace = /[\s\t\r\n]+/ __________________;` *How to ignore???*

**Questions:** 
**-** Does [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com/index.html) support Channels?

**-** What is the Grammar that [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com/index.html) uses to send to a Hidden Channel? 

**-** Alternatively is there anything similar in nature to Channels that would work in ParseKit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creator of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here. ParseKit does not have a `Channels` feature, nor does it have a `->` tree rewrite feature as ANTLR does. (In general, ParseKit is not as fully-featured as ANTLR).

However, you can probably achieve the effect you are looking for using ParseKit's **discard** feature.

When designing your ParseKit grammar, there are often tokens in your language which are pure syntax. These tokens are not important for computing a result nor for building an abstract syntax tree (for further processing). You'll usually want to automatically discard these tokens using the ParseKit `!` directive.

For example, say you have a rule in your ParseKit grammar called `primaryExpr` like:

```
primaryExpr = atom
            | '(' expr ')'!
            ;
```

Notice the `!` after the close parenthesis `')'`. This is the **discard directive** which instructs the ParseKit tokenizer to discard the `)` token from the token stream reported to your ParseKit assembler (delegate) callbacks.

So in your `-parser:didMatchPrimaryExpr:` callback, the `assembly` parameter's stack will not contain the `)` token. The `)` token will have already been discarded. Discarding is desirable in this case, as the `)` is pure syntax which is not important for processing the relevant parenthesized expression.

So to **discard** an unimportant token in your grammar, place a `!` directive immediately after it.

Comment: Todd; Thanks for the well written reply! Would the following code placed in ParseKit's ParseGenApp tell the Generated Parser to discard the set of characters shown?: `whitespace = /[\t\r\n]+/!;` The  grammar rule 'whitespace' isn't being used to define any other rules and is alone.

Comment: Please upvote and/or accept this answer and ask your new question as a new, separate question tagged ParseKit.